# How do I practice Java in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, macos, intellij-idea

Using a Mac.

I am trying to get used to Java so I am following this tutorial https://programmingbydoing.com/a/an-important-message.html

So I made a .java file and opened it in IntelliJ IDEA but somehow I can't get it to run. I did Build and then Run and for some reason there isn't anything I can click to actually run the program. I can only run it from the Terminal if I do `java FirstProg`.

Also I can't seem to get IntelliJ to open these .java files automatically. Any time I click a .java file it opens in XCode. I tried right clicking the .java file and Open With to tell it to always open in IntelliJ but it doesn't seem to stick, and even then it doesn't seem to open the file, it goes to the main IntelliJ menu (Open Project, etc).

Setting up software like this is always a huge weakness for me because I can never get it right. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: IntelliJ (and most other IDEA) revolve around "projects". It is not so useful to just open individual files, as there are usually a lot of dependent files and configuration. Best to create such a project.

Comment: So, you're able to see the java files in the project view?

Comment: That link you posted is severely outdated and uses Notepad, not an IDE such as IntelliJ.... You don't just make a Java file and open it in IntelliJ and expect it to run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The link you posted uses Notepad and compiles Java code from the Command Prompt. While this will work for simple Java files, it is far from a project-based IDE such as IntelliJ.

If you would like a "Getting Stated" then please read [IntelliJ - Creating and Running Your First Java Application](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/creating-and-running-your-first-java-application.html)

Answer (score 1):

Click on "project" near the top left corner to change view to "packages". If it's empty, there's your problem. You may have to create a new one, within that project if you want, then new Java class, and copy over the code. Then it'll compile and run.